# Clicking javascript button with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to click a particular button with Selenium in Python 3.6.but button is not working.

Inspect element ;

```
<span class="jsgrid-pager-page"><a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a></span>
```

I tried this code;

```
page_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("2").click()
```

what should I do?

Comment: Why are you looking for the class name "2"? Do you have such a class?

Comment: Because total page number is 6 but I would like to get the information found on Page 2.

Comment: I added some explanation on my answer about why this didn't work and a post about locators that will help you learning, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You might use link text instead of class name as '2' is not class name for any tag in your HTML code. You can try below code

```
page_button = browser.find_element_by_link_text("2").click();
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"2"}

Answer (score 0):

There is no element in your example that will be found by:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("2").click()
```

You are searching now for a element with the class name 2, so something like `<span class="2">`

You can target the span by the class jsgrid-pager-page, but there wil possibly be more the one occurrence of the class name.

An other possibility is to target the element by xpath, so like:

```
//span/a[text()='2'] 

page_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span/a[text()='2']").click()
```

This way the the driver is going to search for a section containing span and an anchor and a 2.

So when you want to target the first of the third one in the row you just change the number

```
// First
page_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span/a[text()='2']").click()
// Third
page_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span/a[text()='2']").click()
```

I suggest you read something about locators it wil help you in the future: [Locators](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Your `XPath` is incorrect: 1) You should use `//span` instead of just `span`, 2) You use double quotes two times in a single string: both for `XPath` and text value- this will cause an error. You should mix single/double quotes. Also it's bad idea to use `"contains(text(), '2')"` as it will match all links that contains `"2"` text.

Comment: Great catch, I overlooked it, and updated!. your are right about the match, but is more exact than `find_element_by_link_text("2")`. because the xpath only matches on a `<span><a>2</a></span>`

Comment: `find_element_by_link_text("2")` should match exactly the link with text content `"2"` while `find_element_by_xpath("//span/a[contains(text(), '2')]")` will match link with text content `"22"`, `"something 2"` and other links that OP doesn't looking for. If you want to use `XPath`,  you'd better use more explicit predicate `[text()='2']`

Comment: Again you are right, I will update my answer, so it will be more correct

Comment: I copied xpath and result is :
xpath like this : //*[@id="jsGrid"]/div[3]/div/span[4]/a 

How can I configure "find_element_by_xpath"

Comment: Please see the locator reference site: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

Answer (score 0):

If by

> but button is not working.

you mean that the button is not redirecting to some page or doing something, than it might be explained by the `href="javascript:void(0)` attribute inside your `a` tag. The `void` operator after evaluating an expression would return `undefined` in this case, and so the browser will stay in the same page and button click would not do anything.

Please see this SO post for more information about [`href="javascript:void(0)`](http://%60href=%22javascript:void(0)%60)

---

**This is apart from the fact that your locator is not correct. Please fix the locator first.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no class name `"2"` added to target link `HTML`. You might use link text to locate required element. If with [answer provided by @Ankur Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493181/clicking-javascript-button-with-python-3/44493287#44493287) you get `NoSuchElementException` it might mean that link generated dynamically and you should wait for its appearance in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "2"))).click()
```